# Mnesia RPC Call Taking Too long

Tags: database, erlang, distributed-computing, mnesia

```
start(_Type, _Args) ->
  case application:get_env(ebid, join_schema) of
    undefined ->
        mnesia:create_schema([node()]),
        mnesia:start(),
        initialize_tables(),
        mnesia:wait_for_tables([<<set of tables>>], timer:minutes(5));
    {ok, Node} ->
        pong = net_adm:ping(Node),
        join_schema(Node),
        mnesia:wait_for_tables([<<set of tables>>], timer:minutes(5))
end,

join_schema(Node) ->
 case rpc:call('rtb@ip-10-0-43-240', mnesia, change_config, [extra_db_nodes, [node()]]) of
  {ok, _Result} ->
      lists:foreach(fun(Tab) -> io:format("~p : ~p ~n",[Tab,timer:tc(mnesia,add_table_copy,[Tab, node(), ram_copies])]) end, mnesia:system_info(tables));
  {error, Reason} ->
      mnesia:stop(),
      mnesia:del_table_copy(schema, node()),
      error_logger:error_msg("Failed to join schema: ~p~n", [Reason]),
      error(Reason)
end.
```

Is there a way to debug why the join_schema is taking a very long time ? 
We have total of 10 tables in place of "set of tables" and also, overall size is < 400 MB

Only after the join_schema finishes, the worker joins the cluster.

The master node is working fine and has mnesia up.

Comment: Trying to start 4 nodes connecting to the master table all at once

Answer (score 1):

Finally was able to solve the problem. Issue was we follow a auto-scaling policy on EC2 for workers depending on the load. Over a period of time (1 year+) we had many such workers coming in and going out, because of which the master table extra_db_nodes expanded drastically.

Restarting the master solved the issues.